# Make an option selected in select field during form edit in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a form with data which is to edit by user. I am getting form data using $http service of angularJS. I have done all, but I cannot make a select field's option selected (I am new in angularJS). I am setting select field's data in an array like below -

```
$scope.currency = [];
angular.forEach(data.currency, function(data) {
   $scope.currency.push({
        symbol: data.symbol,
        alpha_code: data.alphaCode,
        currency: data.currency
    });
});
```

And in html, I am generating select field like below -

```
<select name="currency_advance" class="form-control" ng-model="invoice_currency">

     <option ng-repeat="data in currency" data-type="{{data.symbol}}" value="{{data.alpha_code}}">{{data.alpha_code + '-' + data.currency}}</option>

</select>
```

Any solution how to make an option selected in angularJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your  like this;

```
<select ng-model="invoice_currency" ng-options="option.alpha_code as option.alpha_code + ' ' + option.currency  for option in currency"></select>
```

And if you want to select the value in your select box do this step in your controller;

```
$scope.invoice_currency = "your select value"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: but if i generate select field using ng-options, the options value becomes 0,1,2,3......, it is not suitable for me, I need some other value like 'USD', 'XSD', 'BDT' etc....

Comment: Don't worry when you inspect the select box the html will always shows values as 0,1,2.. when using ng-options. But actually when you submit the form the value we will be getting is the value we set as the select box's value, in your case it will be USD, XSD etc etc..

Comment: One more change I have done on the answer. I have changed option.symbols to option.alpha_code. Please check it out.

Comment: thanks a lot!!!! it is working. I was worried of using ng-options for 0,1,2.. values......

Comment: Another thing is I am getting 0,1,2... as value while I use $scope.invoice_currency in some other places.... any idea why?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40091/discussion-between-bkm-and-rafi)

Answer (score 1):

You need to start thinking more angular!  Check out the docs for ngSelect: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select and use their directive instead of manually building the `<select>` yourself.